# how to get the frame data in Android

Tags: android, frame, render, stagefright

Recently, I want to develop an android app, I've developed a MediaPlayer to play video ,when the video playing,I want to get the image data of each frame, and do some processing, and then rendering to the screen.Does anybody have suggestions?Thank you in advice!

Comment: I have some situation. Did you have any solution, could you share it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your android version. From Android `JellyBean 4.2.0` onwards, there is a new component introduced as `CPUConsumer` (Reference: [4.2_r1 Sources](http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/native/libs/gui/CpuConsumer.cpp))  which can enable a host program to access an underlying `gralloc` frame.

Some examples to test this functionality is also available in android at [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2_r1/xref/frameworks/native/libs/gui/tests/CpuConsumer_test.cpp).